# Javascript: find position in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg file (whose layout I do not control). The file contains a lot layers (implemented as nested `<g>`) which include translations. I have a circle and I would like to know it's coordinates. Here is a simplified example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
    <g transform="translate(5, 2)">
        <g class="big pos" transform="translate(20, 3)">

            <!-- c is this circle. find the center coords of c -->
            <!-- x = 5 + 20 + 5 + 50 = 80 -->
            <!-- y = 2 + 3 + 4 + 50 = 59 -->
            <circle id="c" transform="translate(5, 4)" class="center" cx="50" cy="50" r="30"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I need a way to find the center coordinates of `c`. So far I have tried this:

```
center = document.getElementById('c');
matrix = center.getCTM();
var mx = matrix.e / Math.abs(matrix.d); 
var my = matrix.f / Math.abs(matrix.d);
// Get cx, cy from center.
// x = mx + cx, y = my + cy
```

This approach has two problems. 1) Any rotations messes up the values. 2) I really have no clue what I'm doing.

What is the proper way of getting the coordinates (relative to the root of the svg) of `c`? Preferably in plain JavaScript, not using D3 or any similar library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps...

```js
var center = document.getElementById('c');
var root = document.getElementById('root');
var point = root.createSVGPoint();
point.x = center.cx.animVal.value;
point.y = center.cy.animVal.value;
var matrix = c.getTransformToElement(root);
var position = point.matrixTransform(matrix);

alert(position.x + ", " + position.y);
```

```html
<svg id="root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
    <g transform="translate(5, 2)">
        <g class="big pos" transform="translate(20, 3)">

            <circle id="c" transform="translate(5, 4)" class="center" cx="50" cy="50" r="30"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This almost does it. It accounts for rotations in a way that my code didn't, however, the values are scaled by the width of the svg-element and the width of the view box. (Running your code snippet yields (515, 378), not (80, 59)). It's pretty trivial to scale myself, but if you update the answer I will select it as the accepted one.

Comment: I didn't realise that was what you wanted. I've changed it to give the numbers you desire now.